# How different are "the tracks" from "the steps" that one leaves in the snow?

Tags: meaning-in-context, difference, literature

Reading a story by A. Blackwood, I am not sure what to make of the following phrase:

> The night was still as ice, bitterly cold. Breathlessly they ran,
> following the tracks. Halfway his steps diverged, and were plainly
> visible in the virgin snow by themselves.

I thought that the tracks in the snow must be logically made of steps - so how can these become visible only halfway?

Comment: More than one set of tracks is present when the author is *following the tracks*.  What becomes visible are *his tracks/steps...by themselves (alone)*, which diverged/separated from the original tracks.

Comment: @EllieK Not sure about that - tracks are used in plural when they mean "marks left". From the Cambridge dictionary: The hunters followed the tracks of the deer for hours

Comment: The plural of deer is deer.  If you choose to believe that there is one set of tracks and someone else's tracks suddenly appear out of nowhere, feel free to make that error but know that that error is why you find the passage confusing.

Comment: @EllieK So one cannot follow tracks of a single deer? In the case of a bike tyre, would it be then "a track"? Thanks a lot

Comment: One *can* follow the tracks of a single deer but that is not what is happening here.  It would be written as you wrote it, *the tracks of the deer (singular)*.  But if there was only one set of tracks, a second set of tracks would not suddenly appear and diverge.  The confusion one might feel over whether or not there is one or many deer is resolved by the fact that the tracks diverge, as they do in your passage.  Many Tracks Together = unknown quantity of deer but once one set of tracks diverge we can assume at least two.  If later another set diverges we can assume at least three, etc, etc.

Comment: One deer leaves tracks behind.  Twenty deer leave tracks behind.  Over time those tracks might form a trail.   In the U.S., steps leave tracks.  There are situations where you might use **track** singularly but I can't think of any easily.  A **track** most commonly means *race track* for horses or cars or monster trucks.

Comment: @EllieK Thanks...so even a single tyre from a bike would leave tracks?

Comment: Good question.  The answer is not clearly defined. The bike would leave a *tire track, tire tracks,* or *tracks*.  We could say to the bike rider, *I followed your tire track to your hideout,* or *I followed your tracks to your hideout or I followed your tire tracks to your hideout.*  But a group of bikers would always leave *tire tracks* behind.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The tracks pre-exist the passage of the person in the story. His steps also make tracks, but when the two sets of tracks diverge, his are made visible because the snow is not disturbed by the previous set.

You are correct that steps make tracks.

Comment: So basically he followed (perhaps) a path that was somehow visible in the snow, and then he went off it?

Comment: Yes, that's what I understand from the quote.

Comment: Note also that non-human animals make tracks although not usually steps so they could conceivably have been following such tracks.

Comment: Nothing is know about the tracks other than there is more than one set and one particular set, **his**, diverges from the many,

Answer (score 2):

This quote seems to imply that there are more than just someone's steps as the "tracks", as his steps are diverging from something else. Without seeing more of the context leading up to this quote it's hard to say.